# How to highlight a missing value in a specified range with Conditional Formatting from the last used column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

We use this format in our casino to know where we have to send our employees to certain tables or games. We recently changed the way we do this and we now need to have some checks to make sure we didn't forget certain tables.

Every hour/half hour/20mins we assign a table to a person, everyone else moves one up. We know exactly which tables are open at which times. We fill this in at the top. When we fill in the upcoming timeslot we would like to have some check so we don't forget a table and maybe miss out a employee.

***Example:***
[image]

In the example supplied you can see that we accidentally have two number 6's but no 7 I highlighted the number 7 in the top row but it would be nice if this is doable automatically

I used `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH` in the formula for Conditional formatting but that does not seem to create the correct outcome.

Comment: Would it be possible to try a different approach, conditional format the cells directly. You will then see both cells with matching numbers highlighted in the column , this will be easier to spot a mistake rather than relying on the header cell and manually trying to find the cells in question.

Comment: But we won't know which number/value we are missing then? Would it be easier to instead working with a row and a column just using columns?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

[image: example]

The formula used has the array `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}` hard written into it, assuming that the number of tables does not vary. The output is 0 when no table is missing, otherwise it returns a list of missing tables separated by commas.

Note: That of course means, the comma separated list is not a numeric value but a string value and cannot be used for further calculations. If further calculations on this output are required, the 'solution' has to be changed accordingly.

### Formula

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(FILTER({1;2;3;4;5;6;7},ISERROR(MATCH({1;2;3;4;5;6;7},H5:H24,0)))&", "),0)
```

### Explanation

The `MATCH()` function checks which of the numbers 1 to 7 are present in the given range (here H5:H24) and returns the cell index of where it is found. When a number does not appear in the range, the `MATCH()` function will generate an #N/A error for that number.

Then, the `ISERROR()` function will output a FALSE value for all numbers found by `MATCH()` and a TRUE value for those numbers where the `MATCH()` function lead to an error.

The `FILTER()` function filters and thereby reduces the number array `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}` to only those numbers where the `ISERROR()` function is TRUE.

The `CONCAT()` function concatenates the resulting array from the `FILTER()` function (in case more than 1 number is missing) to a single string of numbers separated by commas.

However, when there are no open tables, i.e. the `MATCH()` function finds all numbers 1 to 7 in the given range, then the `ISERROR()` function will only return FALSE values and the thus the `FILTER()` function returns an 'empty' array, which is not allowed in excel and leads to an #CALC error in excel. This case is captured by the `IFERROR()` function encapsulating the whole calculation, and instead of showing the error, returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

What about this formula:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,1)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,2)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,3)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,4)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,5)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,6)=1,COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,7)=1)
```

A bit clearer:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,1)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,2)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,3)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,4)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,5)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,6)=1,
     COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,7)=1)
```

... which means that the number of ones need to be 1, the number of twos need to be 1, ..., up to the number of sevens.

Hereby a screenshot of an Excel sheet, which contains that formula:

[image]

In order to understand how this works, you might work with formula auditing, more especially formula evaluating, hereby an extra screenshot, showing formula evaluating after some steps:

[image]

Have fun :-)